# Worklight Push Notification Example

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, push

I'm trying to implement the Push Notification example for hybrid apps provided by IBM, but I get the registration error below. GCM API KEY and PROJECT ID are correctly set in the application-descriptor.XML.

I deployed the APK signed with the distribution certificate in my Nexus 5 (Android 4.2.2), but it doesn't work yet.

Is there anybody able to help me ? I'm working with Worklight Studio 6.2

Thanks.

> GCMRegistrar(29967): resetting backoff for com.PushNotifications
>   GCMRegistrar(29967): Registering app com.PushNotifications of senders
>   testpushgcmproject GCM(1431): GCM config loaded
>   GCMBroadcastReceiver(29967): onReceive:
>   com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
>   GCMBroadcastReceiver(29967): GCM IntentService class:
>   com.PushNotifications.GCMIntentService GCMBaseIntentService(29967):
>   Acquiring wakelock GCMBaseIntentService(29967): Intent service name:
>   GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-2 GCMBaseIntentService(29967):
>   handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = INVALID_SENDER,
>   unregistered = null GCMBaseIntentService(29967): Registration error:
>   INVALID_SENDER GCMBaseIntentService(29967): Releasing wakelock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SENDER_ID = Project Number**,  it can be that you are using the wrong SENDER_ID for example the Project Id.. 
Project Number is available on console beside project id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Project Number. You can see it after accessing your GCM "project":

[image]